# Javascript - Change two function then/catch style into the async/await style

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, callback

I'm try to understand how `.then()` function can get two arguments like this.

```
const promise = doSomething();
const promise2 = promise.then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

or

```
const promise2 = doSomething().then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

but I want to convert two arguments `.then()` to `async/await` like this.

```
const result = await doSomething()
// execute successCallback if success.
// execute failureCallback if failure.
```

This is the website that I'm trying to learn.

[Mozilla Firefox Developer : Using promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

[Mozilla Firefox Developer : Promise Chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `await` a promise that resolves, you directly get its value:

```
const result = await doSomething();
```

When you `await` a promise that rejects, it throws an exception that you can either let propagate back to the caller of the current function (as a rejected promise since all `async` functions return a promise and async functions turn uncaught exceptions into a rejected promise) or you can catch it yourself locally with `try/catch`.

```
try {
   const result = await doSomething();
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

It is not recommended to map promises to callbacks.  It's much better to just return the promise and let the caller deal with the promise directly either with `.then()` or `await`.

If you really needed to map `await` to `successCallback` and `failureCallback`, then you would do this:

```
try {
   const result = await doSomething();
   successCallback(result);
} catch(e) {
   failureCallback(e);
}
```

But, at that point, you may as well just use `.then()` since it's less code:

```
 doSomething().then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

But, as I said earlier, you generally don't want to map promises into callbacks.  It's more likely that you wrap older callback-based APIs into promises so you can use promises for all your control-flow and not mix/match models (which tends to seriously complicate good error handling when you mix models).

Comment: Nice answer, but it's not clear to me what you mean with "don't want to map promises into callbacks".

Comment: @CesarePolonara - Well, you aren't showing a complete set of real code, but the fact that the code appears to have two pre-defined callbacks, one for success and one for failure and you're trying to call them at the right time for the two models makes it appear that this is not native promise code, but rather the caller is passing in two callbacks and you're trying to call them at the right time. That would not be a promise interface - that would be a callback interface.  Instead, just return the promise and let the caller use the promise as needed.   So, this code doesn't call callbacks.

Comment: I'm not the author of the question. Ok I understood what you mean now, but with async functions ( which return promises anyway ) there are some scenarios where you are forced to have impure async functions with side effects callbacks inside of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the doSomething in a try catch method to capture the success and fail like this.

```
try {
const result = await doSomething()
} catch (err) {
console.log(err.message)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try {
  const result = await doSomething()
  // success
  successCallback();
}

catch (e) {
  // error
  failureCallback();
```